# Trust My device

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

How do I go about the following scenario: The first time user logs in from a device MFA is prompted. During MFA if user checks "trust this device" box further logins on the device will need only password.

I am using custom policies.

Answer (score 0):

We do something similar with the IP address, although that may not help if you have a shared IP, you might be able to store a cookie as part of login and then retrieve it using javascript and then enter it into a claim on the login page .